# Authentication free spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

On my application the main page is free an the rest of views requires authetication,now i want to set authentication free for some views i don  know how.

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

How i can set authentication free form  the view `main/webapp/web-inf/views/rooms/list.jspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<http:http pattern="public url pattern" security="none"/>
```

look at [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) document For detail and search for security="none".

Comment: If you are going to suggest that the OP looks at a reference document for details, you should at least provide a link to said document.

Comment: @ebarr added link to reference document